# Oozie: Does oozie generate output-events?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

In oozie, `input-events` are pretty straightforward, if the specifies file/folder is not present, the coordinator job is kept in `WAITING` state. But I could not understand what `output-events` does.

As per my understanding, the files/folders specified in `output-events` tag should be created by oozie in case all specified actions are successful. But that does not happen. I cannot find any relevant logs either. Nor are the documentations clear about this.

So, the question is, does Oozie really create files/folders specified in `output-events`? Or does it just mention that these particular files/folders are created during the workflow and the responsibility of creation is on jobs, not on Oozie?

Relevant piece of code can be found at https://gist.github.com/venkateshshukla/de0dc395797a7ffba153

Comment: If the job submitted to yarn then you can trace the logs in the application master "STDERR" "STDOUT". For oozie you can look at the web UI.

Comment: As I mentioned, logs do not show anything. There is no mention of what happens after the workflow job exits successfully. But I can see that no files/directories are getting created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always the actions generate the data, these settings are just for control.
You'll find some examples [here](http://grokbase.com/t/cloudera/hue-user/12cm7etkjp/oozie-how-to-specify-non-dataset-parameters-to-a-workflow-called-by-coordinator)

Answer (score 6):

The official Oozie documentation for Oozie Coordinator is not very clear on the exact purpose of the `output-events` element. However, the book "Apache Oozie: The Workflow Scheduler for Hadoop" mentions the following:

> During reprocessing of a coordinator, Oozie tries to help the retry attempt by cleaning up the output directories by default. For this, it uses the `<output-events>` specification in the coordinator XML to remove the old output before running the new attempt. Users can override this default behavior using the `–noCleanup` option.

So, in summary:

- No, files specified in `output-events` are not automatically created by Oozie, you need to create those files in your Oozie workflow actions.
- The `output-events` configuration is for giving Oozie information on what files *will* be created by your Oozie workflow actions, which Oozie would use to cleanup files when rerunning/reprocessing a coordinator.